# Firebase Unity SDK doesn't work with custom ROM android device

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

I'm using Firebase Unity SDK for an Unity Android game, it works on normal android devices but fail on custom ROM android devices.These devices have not installed Google Play Services.
Does Firebase Unity just work only on devices have Google Play Services ?
How can i use Firebase services for Unity game on custom ROM android devices?

Answer (score 2):

> Does Firebase Unity just work only on devices have Google Play
>   Services ?

Yes, Firebase requires Google Play Services to function. If you look at all of its examples, you will see `com.google.gms.google-services` in the *build.gradle* dependencies.

> How can i use Firebase services for Unity game on custom ROM android
>   devices?

You need to flash *Google Apps Package* with custom ROM or you have to install ROM with Google Framework. You can see ways to do this [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27808/how-can-i-install-the-google-apps-package-play-store-on-my-android-device).